# Create instance of class from list (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, class

I'm trying to make a simple RPG game. I have a list of people that will be in the game, and want to create a character for each of them.

```
people = ['Mike','Tom']
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = '100'

for x in people:
    [x] = Character(x) # This is where I don't know what to do / if it's possible
```

That way I can call a character easily like

```
for x in people:
    print ("%s: %s health" % (people[x].name, people[x].health))
```

Is such a thing possible, or am I going about this wrong? I read over [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python) but it seemed like dictionaries were the ultimate fix for their problem, and I have no idea how that would work in this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just wanting to keep a list of Character objects. You don't need to reference `people` once you have that.

```
characters = [Character(person) for person in people]
```

Then, to print the character stats:

```
for c in characters:
    print ("%s: %s health" % (c.name, c.health))
```